# Java Regular Expression: matching a customized Hashtag pattern with a lookahead/lookbehind condition

Tags: java, regex

I am currently learning how to write regular expressions in Java by trying to match simple Hashtag pattern. The Hashtags obey the following conditions:

1. It starts with a hashtag: #
2. It has to contain at least 1 letter: [a-zA-Z]
3. It can contain any of the characters from the class [a-zA-Z0-9_]
4. It cannot be preceded by a character of the class [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Based on this, I thought that the correct regular expression is:

```
PATTERN = "(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])#(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
```

Here I'm using a lookahead `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` to make sure Condition 2 holds and using a lookbehind `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])` to make sure Condition 4 holds. I'm less certain about ending with a `+`.

This works on simple test cases but fails on complicated ones such as:

```
String text = "####THIS_IS_A_HASHTAG; ;#This_1_2...#12_and_this but not #123  or #this# #or#that";
```

where does not match `#THIS_IS_A_HASHTAG`, `#This_1_2` and `12_and_this`

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to match this? Running this results in the RE matching all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lookahead:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])
```

may produce wrong results for the cases when input is like this:

```
####12345...#12_and_this
```

by giving you 2 matches `#12345` and `#12_and_this`. Whereas as per your rules only 2nd should be valid match.

To fix this you can use this regex:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])#(?=[0-9_]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

Where lookahead `(?=[0-9_]*[a-zA-Z])` means assert presence of a letter after `#` with optional presence of a digit or underscore in between.

[Here is a regex demo for you](https://regex101.com/r/rW0qG5/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

[(example here)](https://ideone.com/JZNKof)

```
String text = "####THIS_IS_A_HASHTAG;;;#This_1_2...#12_and_this ";
String regex = "#[A-Za-z0-9_]+";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

It looks like it meets your criteria as stated:

```
#THIS_IS_A_HASHTAG
#This_1_2
#12_and_this
```

Comment: You're right. The RegEx you proposed passes the example that I posted yesterday but it does not does not ensure hashtag contains at least 1 letter (which was a condition that I listed but did not include in the example). I've updated the example accordingly. Sorry for that!